# Best chance of survival one bulb or three in a pot?

Tags: flowers, containers

I purchased three dutch iris bulbs but only have one pot to plant them in. To get this highest chance of something coming through should i just plant one of the bulbs and discard the other two or should I put all three in the pot and update the pot later?

Comment: Hi! Pictures of the bulbs and the pot would be helpful. That way we can see the shapes and sizes of both. Also, if your current pot can handle two bulbs but not all three, that's an option.

Answer (score 3):

If your Dutch Iris bulbs look like small pointed onions, they should be planted 4 inches deep and 2-3 inches apart - unless your pot is very small, in which case it's probably not deep enough for even one bulb, you can fit all three into it. Plant with the pointed end upwards, water in, and stand the pot in a sunny area. This answer assumes you're not talking about Iris rhizomes for bearded irises.

If the pot you have isn't deep enough, don't plant, just go and buy a bigger pot, then plant.

Comment: Unless you do something disastrously wrong (like plant the bulbs in soil that is soaked in weedkiller!) you are 99.99% guaranteed to get three out of three. Remember that everything the plant needs to "come through" is already there, inside the bulb. Even if you planted them in a pot full of pure sand instead of compost, they would make an *attempt* to grow and flower, and probably succeed - but they wouldn't survive for a *second* year if you did that, because they wouldn't be able to store up anything in a new bulb.